# Can't invoke gke endpoint directly using cloud scheduler

Tags: api, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-scheduler

Can google cloud scheduler invoke a GKE service endpoint directly bypassing google cloud function?

I wanted to invoke a GKE service endpoint. So , I made a cloud scheduler giving the url of that end-point. But status of my scheduler remains failed. When I check logs , I get

*"status":"UNKNOWN", "targetType":"HTTP"*

Comment: How your endpoint is exposed?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, it is a get endpoint with no authorization

Comment: Can you request this endpoint with a simple CURL?

Comment: Yes, I hit the curl command of this end point with postman and I'm able to get the result.

Comment: Will the cloud scheduler require VPC network to connect to the REST end-point or simply it cannot be done ?

Comment: No, Cloud Scheduler is able to reach any public HTTP endpoint. However, if your endpoint is private, you can't use CLoud Scheduler, but use a Cloud Function/Cloud Run that proxy your request and forward it through the serverless VPC connector

Comment: Thanks, my end point is indeed private

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.